# How to figure out the body structure of a REST request job?

Tags: java, rest, http, talend, data-integration

I'm trying to transform Talend jobs to Spring Boot REST services. But I can't figure out the body of this post request.

Job 1 picture illustrates a JSON extract, and subjob picture is other in loop JSON extract, so I suppose the expected JSON is something like this:

```
{
    "user": "alvaro",
    "flight": [
        {
            "flightUID": "1",
            "infoSusp": "xx",
            "medSusp": "otr aprueba"
        },
            {
            "flightUID": "2",
            "infoSusp": "xx",
            "medSusp": "otr aprueba"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I always receive bad request response.

Job 1:

[image]

Subjob 2:

[image]

Comment: I don't know the particular program that you're using. Is it aware that `flight` is an array of objects and not just an object with properties?

Because `[{foo:bar}]` isn't the same as `{foo:bar}`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to know what is the structure of your json input in tFixedFlow_1 ? Then just put a tLogRow after this component to print the json content, and make sure it is the structure you are looking for

Comment: I solved it. Flgiht wasn´t an array. Loop XPath query is for iterate over the flight fields, not over flights